# How to compute the intercept of a square with a line given by two points?

Tags: geometry

Suppose I have a point in a square, with side length s and two sides along the x/y-axes, not necessarily the center, and a point outside of the square. What is a function that computes the intercept between the sides of the square and the line given by those two points? I'm having trouble with the inherent piecewise nature of the problem, since the four lines are different, and I need this for some code.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are trying to find the point $(x, y)$ in [this diagram](https://puu.sh/wPF7z/d02260188b.png) given arbitrary points $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$? I wasn't completely sure from your question.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Alright let's start with some definitions:

$s$ is the side length of the square (which is centered at $(0, 0)$).

$(x_1, y_1)$ is the point *inside* the square.

$(x_2, y_2)$ is the point *outside* the square.

$(x_i, y_i)$ is the point of intersection.

I'm not going to explicitly answer everything for you, but I'll give you some hints. First, think of this as an extension of finding the $x$-intercept or $y$-intercept of a curve. To do that, you set $y$ or $x$ (respectively) to be $0$. How can that be related to a line with a square?

It is also helpful to know the equation of the line:
\begin{align}y - y_1 &= m(x - x_1)\\
(x_2-x_1)(y-y_1)&= (y_2-y_1)(x-x_1)\end{align}

So what I would do is check the intercepts of this line with the "axes" of the square, and if they lie within the piecewise constraints (e.g. $0<x<s$), there's your answer. Just be careful for lines going through the corner of the square and if $\Delta x$ or $\Delta y$ is 0. If you're still confused, I can give some more hints.

Comment: I already know all of this. The lines for the squares are of course x=0, y=0, x=s and y=s.  I'm having trouble with the piecewise part of the problem. It's not straightforward to know which of the four sides the line made by the points intercepts. It will require at least some trig because the line made by the points will always intersect two points on the square, but I need to pick the one that is closer.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure what you knew. I assumed that since this is a coding problem you can just do a bunch of clauses. If you're looking for a logical way to determine which side of the square, there'd probably be some weird trig in there and just as much casework. I think it's better to just check each side manually (check where x=0 and the line between the two points intersect, then see if that's on a square side. If not, try the next side. There's exactly one intersect so this will work with one of the four sides). Does that make sense?

Comment: Well, actually this doesn't work since any line you make going through a square will intersect two sides, not just one (the one in between the points and the one you get if you extend the line to the other side of the square).

Comment: Alright I'm going to write the code in my answer, give me a few minutes.